# How to use different panels in a grouped list view?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I need to use a different panel for a particular section/group in my ListView. How do I do that (using XAML, C#, or anything)? I already tried using `GroupedStyleSelector` but it didn't work (I researched about it but it turned out it's not designed for this purpose). Here's my XAML right now:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}">
    <ListView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="True">
            <GroupStyle.Panel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    // I want to change this for a particular group
                    <uwp:SGStaggeredPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.Panel>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ListView.GroupStyle>
</ListView>
```

I'm thinking of subclassing the panel, but the problem is how do I get a reference to the current group?

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/extensions/listviewbase

The above article talks about a WCT goody that allows you to dynamically change the Tamplate of the item that is about to be rendered, this particular example is a statically expressed extension that simply works as an attached property to a listview and cycles through two different templates

But you can easily extend ListView into a templated control and then more easily have access to the Viewmodel that houses your Itemsource, from then you can go on to change the

```
 private static void ItemTemplateContainerContentChanging(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewBase sender, ContainerContentChangingEventArgs args)
```

which is where all the magic takes place.

Notation for implementation

### Note 0:

if you don't know mvvm and binding, forget you ever read this and go study it up instead.

### Note 1:

All child controls that have no explicitly defined Data Context will inherit their parents.

### Note 2:

You will be able to Map incoming controls in the aforementioned function by tracking the incoming args.ItemIndex and then cross checking it with the binded source (Observable list etc) that is housed on the underlying datacontext.

### Note 3:

To convert this into a tamplated/custom control you will have to pretty much make your own implementation of  ListView like this MyListview:ListView

The Dependency properties will have to be converted to conventional ones,
just type 'propdp' and double tap Tab, to bring up the default tamplate.

You will still have to reference all the different DataTamplates from XAML like its shown in the showcase app listed bellow.

### Note 4:

Cut the slack off that showcase code, the stretch direction and the zebra stripes for example are not needed in your case.

https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI/Extensions/ListViewBase/ListViewExtensions.cs

this is the exact location of the code piece i talked about, to check it out in action and play with it, Download 'Windows Community Toolkit' from the store, it is in the Extensions section.